# how do I transition from a cocos2d scene to a uiviewcontroller view?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

Just want to know how to transition from a cocos2d scene to a UIviewcontroller view and vice-versa?

thanks, 
mark

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D lives in a view, specifically a EAGLView (a subclass of UIView) - that it creates.

Transitioning is not as cut and dry as it seems, especially if using one of the built in templates, cocos2d lives in a new UIWindow (that it creates in your "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions" function).

-
You have to create a new view based application, and add cocos2d as a subview of that in order for it to work.

The structure would look like this:

```
UIViewController (A subclass you created)
 --View (iOS makes this by default for your UIViewController)
   -- CocosView (You make this using [UIView initWithFrame:] )
      -- EAGLView (CCDirector creates on init)
   -- Regular UIKit View ( You make this )
```

Comment: I had to do the exact same thing, an i wrote about my process here (LINK SPAM DISCLAIMER i dunno what the policy is but yes this is a link to my own blog entry on steps towards accomplishing the above task) http://www.learningiphone.com/?p=187